# Does Adobe Premiere Pro CS6 have a fullscreen mode?

Tags: video-editor, premiere, editing

Essentially what I'm looking for is a way to make Adobe Premiere Pro CS6 go fullscreen. I do not mean the fullscreen preview of the video or fullscreen on a specific panel (like the timeline).

I want to get rid of the Windows taskbar and the window border. The same way that you would go fullscreen with a browser by pressing F11.

I'm surprised I haven't found any shortcut or any discussion online. I'm working on a 15" laptop monitor and would like to maximize my workspace. I've tried to press F11, searched for it in the menus and the keyboard shortcut list but haven't found anything.

As clarified in the comments on AJ's answer below, I am looking for something like pushing F in Photoshop or Lightroom, where the workspace is otherwise the same.  For example, this is how it looks in Lightroom.
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You said you are trying to maximize your workspace, did you try CTRL + tilde ('~') while hovering the mouse over the panel that you are interested in. (The CTRL option removes the menu bars) To get rid of the taskbars on the operating system, you would need to set it to hide via the operating system in question.

Comment: @eLouai Hello! Which language had you set on your keyboard when you tried that? I tried that command with English keyboard but with no luck. In After Effects, tilde maximises the panel I hover over whilst ' on a English keyboard does that in Premiere. But yep, I'll have to stick with the hide taskbar option:P Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm fairly certain there is no such mode.  It doesn't have the same kind of feature that lightroom does as the full screen video preview is really the closest in terms of being related functionality.

The full screen mode is helpful in Lightroom because it allows focusing on the photo with only basic controls.  Premiere is much more complex than LR and a significant portion of screen real-estate is taken up by those controls.  If you aren't purely focusing on the video, then the amount of lost and distracting space really isn't a big issue.

Note that if you really need every last scrap of screen real estate though, you can adjust the task bar so that you can make it only a small line on the bottom of the screen though.  You really are not practically losing any meaningful amount of screen real-estate.

The only functionality is the functionality that maximizes a particular panel or full screens the preview, but you already mentioned those are not what you are looking for.  That's the closest you are going to get though.

Comment: Alright. It's not just that I want more space, but want it to be more immerse. And the border and the taskbar takes up approximately 13% of my screen, which I think could show one more track of videos.

Photoshop has the fullscreen mode I'm refering to(shortcut: F on Swedish keyboard), which has a quite complex UI as well. Don't see why Premiere wouldn't have a similar feature.

I didn't think of the hide taskbar setting, though. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: @Thelemic - if your task bar and borders are taking up 13% of your screen, you may seriously want to consider getting a higher resolution display if possible.  It will make a huge difference in usability for something like Premiere.  I would also suggest setting the task bar to hide so that you can have it go away when you aren't using it.

Comment: Haha, yeah.:D I'm going to buy a new laptop in the near future and I'm going for a 1920x1080 screen then. In also considering a 17" screen:P. And yes, I set my taskbar to hide, now that you mentioned it. Had completely forgot about that feature.

Answer (score -3):

Another option is to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> to get **full screen preview**.

Comment: This is full screen preview, which is specifically NOT what the OP was asking about.  This answer is simply wrong.

Comment: @AJHenderson Why not deleting this answer?

Comment: Unfortunately being wrong isn't grounds for deleting an answer. It lacks explanation, but if it was correct it would still be enough explanation. The reasoning behind this is that we could all be the ones wrong. Maybe we misunderstood the op. In this case I know that isn't the case but where is the line of being sure enough and how do I know I'm not wrong despite being "certain"?